# Wordpress Permalink issue with Custom Post Type, only works if I'm logged in

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

I'm pulling my hair out and hope someone can help. I have created a custom post type - **event**.

```
add_action('init', 'event'); // Events post-type
function event()
{
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'event');
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'event');
    register_post_type('event',
        array(
        'labels' => array(
         'name' => __('Events', 'event'),
         'singular_name' => __('Event', 'event'),
         'add_new' => __('Add New', 'event'),
         'add_new_item' => __('Add New Event', 'event'),
         'edit' => __('Edit', 'event'),
         'edit_item' => __('Edit Event', 'event'),
         'new_item' => __('New Event', 'event'),
         'view' => __('View Event', 'event'),
         'view_item' => __('View Event', 'event'),
         'search_items' => __('Search Event', 'event'),
         'not_found' => __('No Events found', 'event'),
         'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Events found in Trash', 'event')
     ),
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
     'has_archive' => true,
     'supports' => array(
         'title',
         'editor',
         'excerpt',
         'thumbnail'
     ),
        'taxonomies' => array(
         'post_tag',
         'category'
     ) // Add Category and Post Tags support
 ));
}
```

In the **Events.php** template file, for the Events page, I query for the post type using:

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=event&order=ASC&post_status=future'); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<li>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">    
        ...
    </a>
</li>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And then there's **single-event.php** of course.

So, if I'm LOGGED IN to wordpress in the browser, I can get to the single event pages no problem. But if I'm logged out, they return the 404 page, as well as any other computer I try to open them on.
I ahev no cache software running, I've visited the Permalinks page after every adjustment, and the .htaccess file looks fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In your Events.php template you have :

`<?php query_posts('post_type=event&order=ASC&post_status=future'); ?>`

The `post_status` is set to "`future`", so you would only see those posts if your're logged in.  If you're logged out, you won't see them, even if they *are* published, unless their post date is earlier than the date you're viewing the event.

Comment: This. Post status of future means it is not published. Try a new WP_Query instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling:

```
flush_rewrite_rules();
```

after:

```
register_post_type('event',
    array(
    'labels' => array(
     'name' => __('Events', 'event'),
     'singular_name' => __('Event', 'event'),
     'add_new' => __('Add New', 'event'),
     'add_new_item' => __('Add New Event', 'event'),
     'edit' => __('Edit', 'event'),
     'edit_item' => __('Edit Event', 'event'),
     'new_item' => __('New Event', 'event'),
     'view' => __('View Event', 'event'),
     'view_item' => __('View Event', 'event'),
     'search_items' => __('Search Event', 'event'),
     'not_found' => __('No Events found', 'event'),
     'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Events found in Trash', 'event')
 ),
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true,
 'has_archive' => true,
 'supports' => array(
     'title',
     'editor',
     'excerpt',
     'thumbnail'
 ),
    'taxonomies' => array(
     'post_tag',
     'category'
 ) // Add Category and Post Tags support
));
```

Or add this to the arguments array:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'event','with_front' => FALSE),
```

So you end up with:

```
register_post_type('event',
    array(
    'labels' => array(
     'name' => __('Events', 'event'),
     'singular_name' => __('Event', 'event'),
     'add_new' => __('Add New', 'event'),
     'add_new_item' => __('Add New Event', 'event'),
     'edit' => __('Edit', 'event'),
     'edit_item' => __('Edit Event', 'event'),
     'new_item' => __('New Event', 'event'),
     'view' => __('View Event', 'event'),
     'view_item' => __('View Event', 'event'),
     'search_items' => __('Search Event', 'event'),
     'not_found' => __('No Events found', 'event'),
     'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Events found in Trash', 'event')
 ),
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true,
 'has_archive' => true,
 'supports' => array(
     'title',
     'editor',
     'excerpt',
     'thumbnail'
 ),
    'taxonomies' => array(
     'post_tag',
     'category'
 ),
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'event','with_front' => FALSE),
));
```

Comment: I tried this - added it right before the last ));, but it doesn't work. Same results. (I visited the Permalinks page afterwards too).

Comment: Did you also double check the post status? Is it published?

Comment: yup, the posts are published and show just fine on the main Events page. It's just the single event that goes to 404. But only if I;m logged out from the admin backend. If I log in, and then in a new tab try to go to one of the events, they pull up just fine, using the exact same URL as previously.

Comment: I tried that last part you added also and still no luck.

Comment: Yeah, and still have the same results. I tried your rewrite option also, just as you have it above.

Answer (score 0):

There are several arguments to `register_post_type` that I don't see that may make a difference. Try out some of these:

```
'public' => true, // Master 
    'publicly_queryable' => false, // must be set to true to use in a template
    'exclude_from_search' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
    'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite'   => array( 'slug' => 'custom_type', 'with_front' => false ), 
    'has_archive' => 'custom_type',
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the post status?
If the eveent post is scheduled post, only logged-in user can access the page. otherwise they can see 404 page.